# How can I detect if CDRom is a DVD on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, dvd, cd-rom, cddvd

I'm looking to create a function in C++ running on Linux that returns true if the CDRom media is a DVD and false if its anything else (e.g. Audio CD).

I have been using `ioctl` with `linux/cdrom.h`.
I tried using the `DVD_READ_STRUCT` but it always returns true. Maybe I'm using it incorrectly.

```
dvd_struct s
if (ioctl(hDEV, DVD_READ_STRUCT, &s)) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What do you actually care about?  If it's an audio CD or not; or if it's a DVD or CD?

Comment: @UKMonkey _"returns true if the CDRom media is a DVD and false if its anything else"_

Comment: At first glance I can't see a feature in that header for that

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "false if its anything else (ie. Audio CD)" -   this false assumption prompted the question..,. remember, people don't ask the question they mean to!

Comment: @UKMonkey Seems more likely that it's a misspelling of "e.g." (which is very common; also see the title) but fair enough!

Comment: there's also the fact that blueray has been completely ignored ... do you care about that at all?

Comment: OP can you make a guess from the media size?

Comment: I only care if its a DVD. Any other format should return false (including Bluray). Different DVD media of varying sizes will be used so IDK how media size can help

Comment: _Maybe_ [these macros](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/cdrom.h#L387) somewhere in [this struct](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/cdrom.h#L91) in [this struct](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/cdrom.h#L41) as returned by `CDROM_DISC_STATUS`. But it seems to be that this whole API is designed to be largely media-agnostic. Which begs the question - why do you want to know?

Comment: _"IDK how media size can help"_ Do DVDs of CD or Bluray size exist?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_disc#Overview_of_optical_types - CD  0.7–0.9 GB;   DVD 4.7–17 GB;  BlueRay: 25 GB;   There's no overlap; so for a "make do" version it'll work

Comment: You can also check how existing apps handle the situation. Like [Cdrdao Homepage](http://cdrdao.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @UKMonkey. Sizing might work then, but now the question is how do I get the total size of the disc?

Comment: Years ago, I had a project where I needed to burn files directly to DVDs. I don't know how to do this in Linux, but on Windows, [I used `DeviceIoControl()` to issue Multimedia MMC commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23024802/65863) directly to the optical drives to query the disc type, write status, capacities, etc. If anything other than a DVD was detected, or if a DVD was already written to, I didn't burn the files. This was at a time before Microsoft added better APIs to query devices for such information (or maybe I just wasn't aware of those APIs yet).

Answer (score 1):

Look at `/proc/sys/dev/cdrom/info`, it contains something like this:

```
CD-ROM information, Id: cdrom.c 3.20 2003/12/17

drive name:         sr0
drive speed:        125
drive # of slots:   1
Can close tray:     1
Can open tray:      1
Can lock tray:      1
Can change speed:   1
Can select disk:    0
Can read multisession:  1
Can read MCN:       1
Reports media changed:  1
Can play audio:     1
Can write CD-R:     1
Can write CD-RW:    1
Can read DVD:       1
Can write DVD-R:    1
Can write DVD-RAM:  1
Can read MRW:       0
Can write MRW:      0
Can write RAM:      1
```

(it is updated by the kernel and available in all distros)
You can use this information in addition to the `ioctl`'s from `cdrom.h`. Also keep in mind that `cdrom.h` is an attempt to create a standard interface, it does not yet cater for all manufacturers, some still using SCSI-codes or some other proprietary schemes. So to be safe you should also check at least using the SCSI `ioctl` codes - do `#include <scsi/...` to have them available.

Comment: The question is about the media (CD or DVD), this answer is about drive capabilities, that exist and are constant whether a disc is in the drive or not. It cannot answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

[The official documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/userspace-api/ioctl/cdrom.html) is a bit more helpful.  You have to specify the request type and any required inputs before calling `ioctl`.

```
// Is it a DVD?
dvd_struct ds;
ds.type = DVD_STRUCT_PHYSICAL;
ds.physical.layer_num=0;
result = ioctl(drive, DVD_READ_STRUCT, &ds);

if (result == -1) {
    perror("Probably not a DVD: ");
} else {
    printf("Layer 0: %i to %i.\n", ds.physical.layer[0].start_sector, ds.physical.layer[0].end_sector);
}
```

The really interesting stuff requires issuing SCSI commands like [dvd+rw-tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvd%2Brw-tools), [cdrkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cdrkit), and [cdrdao](https://github.com/cdrdao/cdrdao/).  Doing this is a bit painful, though, and it's not necessary if you don't need to know if the disc is recordable, rewritable, or pressed.